# Kohana: I want to use Auth model for login using normal role user, how can i achieve this using active records?

Tags: php, authentication, kohana

I am using Kohana active records, and using its classes added user name and its role in users and roles_users tables which are in sync as mentioned below:

Added these values manually in DB:

```
mysql> select *from users;
+----+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------+
| id | email       | username | password | logins | last_login |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------+
|  1 | abc@abc.com | Tito     | password |    123 |       1234 |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from roles_users;
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

// This table and its data are there from default database
mysql> select * from roles;
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name  | description                                          |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | login | Login privileges, granted after account confirmation |
|  2 | admin | Administrative user, has access to everything.       |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now when i am using below mentioned code to login, it is returning false.

```
$post =  Auth::instance()->login("Tito", "password");
```

Can you please guide what i need to do?

Also auth, database, ORM modules are uncommented.

auth.php file context is from application/config/auth.php:

```
return array(

'driver'       => 'file',
'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
'hash_key'     => 'Somebiglonghaskeyofmixedcharacters102345567709',
'lifetime'     => 1209600,
'session_type' => Session::$default,
'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

// Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
'users' => array(
    // 'admin' => 'b3154acf3a344170077d11bdb5fff31532f679a1919e716a02',
),

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add password in table manually? Did you use $auth->hash($password) before adding a pass in table ?
When you are trying to login kohana login method create a hashed password. Becouse of this you cant login (password != hash(password))

```
protected function _login($user, $password, $remember)
{

     ......

    if (is_string($password))
    {
        // Create a hashed password
        $password = $this->hash($password);
    } 
     ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it was due to adding password manually. I found that it was not hashed when i added it.